Retrieving news articles from Yahoo Finance Canada website
I am trying to retrive all news articles about a company whose stock symbol is TECK-B.TO that were published in 2024 in Yahoo Finance Canada.  The articles can be seen in this URL:
https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TECK-B.TO/news.
As can be seen, there are over 50 articles about that company in the above URL.
Using Databricks and the below Python code, I have been able to retrieve 2 of the articles.
I would like to retrieve all articles in the above URL that were published in 2024.
I have tried using this code:
# Install necessary libraries
# %pip install requests beautifulsoup4 pandas

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType
from datetime import datetime

def fetch_tmx_news_2024():
    url = "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TECK-B.TO/news/"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    articles = []

    for item in soup.find_all('li', class_='js-stream-content'):
        link = item.find('a')['href'] if item.find('a') else None
        title = item.find('a').text if item.find('a') else None
        date_str = item.find('time')['datetime'] if item.find('time') else None

        # Debug print to check each article's details
        print(f"Title: {title}, Link: {link}, Date: {date_str}")

        if date_str:
            date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
            print(f"Parsed Date: {date}")  # Debug print to check parsed date
            if date.year == 2024:
                articles.append({
                    'title': title,
                    'link': f"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com{link}" if link else None,
                    'date': date
                })

    # Debug print to check the articles list
    print("Articles found: ", articles)

    schema = StructType([
        StructField("title", StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField("link", StringType(), nullable=True),
        StructField("date", TimestampType(), nullable=True)
    ])

    if articles:
        return spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(articles), schema=schema)
    else:
        print("No articles found for the year 2024.")
        return spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(columns=['title', 'link', 'date']), schema=schema)

# Invocation of the function
news_df = fetch_tmx_news_2024()

# Display Spark DataFrame
display(news_df)

I am expecting to retrieve all articles about the above mentioned company that were published in the year 2024 in the above mentioned URL (https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/TECK-B.TO/news/).

Details:
based on your expectations, I think using the requests library and a little bit of code can fetch your desired result, here is my mindmap:
We can use their API endpoint https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/caas/content/article/?uuid={UUIDS}&appid=article2_csn to get all the info such as date, title, and news URL.
first:
we have to find All the news UUID (something like article UUID), we need to send a request to this endpoint https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/_finance_doubledown/api/resource?bkt=finance-CA-en-CA-def&device=desktop&ecma=modern with JSON data on post body (You need to use your target company name as value of the catagory param, example: TECK-B.TO)
here is the simple script that fetches at least 100+ news article URLs:
import requests
import re
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def getUuids(companyName):
    url = 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/_finance_doubledown/api/resource?bkt=finance-CA-en-CA-def&device=desktop&ecma=modern'
    data = {"requests":{"g0":{"resource":"StreamService","operation":"read","params":{"forceJpg":True,"releasesParams":{"limit":50,"offset":0},"ncpParams":{"query":{"id":"tickers-news-stream","version":"v1","namespace":"finance","listAlias":"finance-CA-en-CA-ticker-news"}},"useNCP":True,"batches":{"pagination":True,"size":10,"timeout":1500,"total":170},"category":f"YFINANCE:{companyName}"}}}}
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    resp = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, verify=False).json()
    return resp['g0']['data']['stream_pagination']['gqlVariables']['tickerStream']['pagination']['uuids']


def getDetails(companyName):
    result = getUuids(companyName)
    remove_junk = re.sub(':STORY|:VIDEO', '', result)
    result_url = f'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/caas/content/article/?uuid={remove_junk}&appid=article2_csn'
    result_resp = requests.get(result_url, verify=False).json()
    for i in result_resp['items']:
        try:
            news_modifiedDate = i['data']['partnerData']['modifiedDate']
            if '2024' in news_modifiedDate:
                news_urls = i['data']['partnerData']['finalUrl']
                news_title = i['data']['partnerData']['pageTitle']
                print(f"News URL:  {news_urls}\nModifiedDate: {news_modifiedDate}\nTitle: {news_title}\n=================")
        except Exception:
            pass

getDetails('TECK-B.TO')

I think this can help you to get all the news article URLs, dates, and titles for a specific company.

for quick information, I didn't add your code in the answer section as a replacement because I am getting keyError in return spark.createDataFrame line, that's why I didn't try this out.

It worked.  Thank you very much!
